# How can I make user-defined highlight for C# in VS Code

Tags: c#, visual-studio-code

Recently I installed VS Code and C# plugin for it. I must say that I really like the editor. It is very lightweight and highly customizable. However I haven't found how can I redefine several colorization options such as highlighting classes inside field definitions or local variables?

I already use standard C# colorizer. I just want to customize the color of some lexemes, not everything.

Answer (score 2):

Checkout the docs here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/colorizer

You basically either get one from the marketplace or generate a basic editable file with yeoman.

You can also add themes even from color sublime as described here:

https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/themes

Comment: Couldn't I just edit some existing configuration file for C# syntax? I mean, I already installed C# extension, and I just want to reconfigure several highlight colors, not rewrite all of them from scratch.

Comment: You can extend existing syntax highlighting. Check out the last two QA (at the bottom of the page) here: https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/customization/colorizer

Comment: All of this is describing how to generate some meaningless packages and whatenot. Where can I actually redefine the color for specific language lexems? I generated and installed C# theme with this yo package, what now? Where can I actually edit the color itself? I opened the tmTheme file and it contains tons of garbage without clear structure and colorization options.

Comment: VS Code relies on .tmLanguage files to define grammar etc. You provide one that suits your needs and include it inside the configuration either as a new language, an extension to an existing grammar or an entire override.

Comment: So I need to dive into tmLanguage format, study it for hours and then find out how to change the color of one simple thing, right?

Comment: Oh well... stated like that it actually sounds super annoying. Yes that's atleast how I came to know it (and how it's documented). I suggest you grab an existing .tmLanguage file for C#, try to get the gist of it and modify the needed places.

Comment: @GuardianX nothing comes for free. You either do it yourself, or wait for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Install theme from extensions from which you wish to start.

Then find where the theme got installed. On Windows it would be `%USERPROFILE%\.vscode\extensions`, see details in [Installing extensions](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/extensions/install-extension).

There you'll find folder with theme, inside is `themes` folder and `<something>.tmTheme` file which is actually xml file. Open it inside VSCode and start editing :)

You'll find items and colors, syntax is described elsewhere, but common sense will help you.

To test change, open desired .cs file in same editor. Changes are applied after restart, so it's also good to make [key shortcut](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/customization/keybindings) to restart the editor:

keybindings.json

```
...
{
   "key": "ctrl+shift+alt+r",
   "command": "workbench.action.reloadWindow"
}
...
```

Then try color, restart, see result, continue...